# Scraping Javascript-rendered webpage that references external javascript scripts in R

Tags: javascript, r, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape this webpage: https://www.mustardbet.com/sports/events/302698

Since the webpage seems to be rendered dynamically, I am following this tutorial:
https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scraping-javascript-generated-data-with-r#gs.dZEqev8

As the tutorial suggests, I save a file named "scrape_mustard.js" with the following code:

```
// scrape_mustard.js

var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var fs = require('fs');
var path = 'mustard.html'

page.open('https://www.mustardbet.com/sports/events/302698', function (status) {
  var content = page.content;
  fs.write(path,content,'w')
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Then, I perform

```
system("./phantomjs scrape_mustard.js")
```

but I get the error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Set

  https://www.mustardbet.com/assets/js/index.dfd873fb.js:1
  https://www.mustardbet.com/assets/js/index.dfd873fb.js:1 in t
  https://www.mustardbet.com/assets/js/index.dfd873fb.js:1
  https://www.mustardbet.com/assets/js/index.dfd873fb.js:1 in t
  https://www.mustardbet.com/assets/js/index.dfd873fb.js:1
  https://www.mustardbet.com/assets/js/index.dfd873fb.js:1 in t
  https://www.mustardbet.com/assets/js/index.dfd873fb.js:1
  https://www.mustardbet.com/assets/js/index.dfd873fb.js:1 in t
  https://www.mustardbet.com/assets/js/index.dfd873fb.js:1
```

Now, when I paste "https://www.mustardbet.com/assets/js/index.dfd873fb.js" into my browser I can see that it's javascript, and that I probably need to either
(1) save that as a file, or 
(2) include it in scrape_mustard.js.

But if (1), I don't know how to then reference that new file, and if (2), I don't know how to define all that javascript properly so that it can be used.

I'm a complete newbie to javascript, but maybe this problem is not too difficult?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Of course, if anyone has a way of scraping this page by an alternative R method I'd be very happy to hear it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to scrape using the js module `puppeteer.js`.

Download `node.js` [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). `node.js` comes with `npm` which makes your life easier when comes to install modules. You need to install puppeteer using `npm`.

In RStudio, make sure you are on your working directory when you are installing `puppeteer.js`. Once `node.js` is installed, do ([source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer)):

`system("npm i puppeteer")`

`scrape_mustard.js`:

```
// load modules
const fs = require("fs");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

// page url
url = "https://www.mustardbet.com/sports/events/302698";

scrape = async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false}); // open browser
    const page = await browser.newPage(); // open new page
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 0}); // go to page
    await page.waitFor(5000); // give it time to load all the javascript rendered content
    const html = await page.content(); // copy page contents
    browser.close(); // close chromium
    return html // return html object
};

scrape().then((value) => {
    fs.writeFileSync("./stackoverflow/page.html", value) // write the object being returned by scrape()
});
```

To run `scrape_mustard.js` in `R`:

```
library(magrittr)

system("node ./stackoverflow/scrape_mustard.js")

html <- xml2::read_html("./stackoverflow/page.html")

oddsMajor <- html %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes(".odds-major")

betNames <- html %>% 
  rvest::html_nodes("h3")
```

Console output:

```
{xml_nodeset (60)}
 [1] <span class="odds-major">2</span>
 [2] <span class="odds-major">14</span>
 [3] <span class="odds-major">15</span>
 [4] <span class="odds-major">16</span>
 [5] <span class="odds-major">17</span>
 [6] <span class="odds-major">23</span>
 [7] <span class="odds-major">25</span>
 [8] <span class="odds-major">32</span>
 [9] <span class="odds-major">33</span>
[10] <span class="odds-major">39</span>
[11] <span class="odds-major">47</span>
[12] <span class="odds-major">54</span>
[13] <span class="odds-major">55</span>
[14] <span class="odds-major">58</span>
[15] <span class="odds-major">58</span>
[16] <span class="odds-major">64</span>
[17] <span class="odds-major">73</span>
[18] <span class="odds-major">73</span>
[19] <span class="odds-major">92</span>
[20] <span class="odds-major">98</span>
...
> betNames
{xml_nodeset (60)}
 [1] <h3>Charles Howell III</h3>\n
 [2] <h3>Brian Harman</h3>\n
 [3] <h3>Austin Cook</h3>\n
 [4] <h3>J.J. Spaun</h3>\n
 [5] <h3>Webb Simpson</h3>\n
 [6] <h3>Cameron Champ</h3>\n
 [7] <h3>Peter Uihlein</h3>\n
 [8] <h3>Seung-Jae Im</h3>\n
 [9] <h3>Nick Watney</h3>\n
[10] <h3>Graeme McDowell</h3>\n
[11] <h3>Zach Johnson</h3>\n
[12] <h3>Lucas Glover</h3>\n
[13] <h3>Corey Conners</h3>\n
[14] <h3>Luke List</h3>\n
[15] <h3>David Hearn</h3>\n
[16] <h3>Adam Schenk</h3>\n
[17] <h3>Kevin Kisner</h3>\n
[18] <h3>Brian Gay</h3>\n
[19] <h3>Patton Kizzire</h3>\n
[20] <h3>Brice Garnett</h3>\n
...
```

I am sure it can be done with `phantomjs` but I've found `puppeteer` easier to scrape javascript-rendered webpages. Also keep in mind that `phantomjs` [is no longer being developed](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344).