# How to use the remote driver on a proxy-protected computer through the R software package RSelenium?

Tags: html, r, proxy, rvest

Well, I need to access a site in the work network (in company), however it is protected by proxy.

Some sites accept httr and rvest packages, others do not. I can not log in to sites. Example:

```
pro <- use_proxy ("my.proxy", port, "myuser", "myhaha")
my_session <- html_session (url, pro)
```

I usually use this proxy function to access the url I want and go through the proxy.

But in certain sites, in case to log in, this function does not run, or rather I can not login.

The alternative I found was to use a remote driver using the `rsDriver(browser = c("chrome"))` function, for example. On my personal pc I can unroll all the code through the remote driver of the RSelenium Package. Now I can not work on the work network. The best options I found by searching were:

1)

```
cprof <- list (chromeOptions = list (
args = c ('-proxy-server = http: //minha.proxy: port',
         '--proxy-auth = username: password')))
driver <- rsDriver (browser = c ("chrome"), extraCapabilities = cprof)
```

2)

```
cprof <- list (chromeOptions = list (
args = c ('-proxy-server = http: // ip: port',
         '--proxy-auth = username: password')))
driver <- rsDriver (browser = c ("chrome"), extraCapabilities = cprof)
```

This to pass in the proxy, but returns in all:

```
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
Error in open.connection (with, "rb"):
  Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10000 milliseconds
```

This error is what usually happens when it does not pass the proxy (I think!).

So, do have some way to go through the proxy and open my remote driver?
Well, have something to contribute, I'll be grateful!

Comment: I solved the problem in part. I changed the environment variables (as in: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40044773/10749690)) and then followed the steps described here ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53343238/10749690)). If you have something to supplement, I am at your disposal.

Comment: I solved part of my problem and the answer I put in: [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/355615/75120)